# Help! jquery-UI datepicker function onChangeMonthYear() the parameter of "month" no leading zero

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { ... }
});
```

I just want the month parameter with leading zero!

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with only a 2 digit scenario you can do take a simple check approach:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { 
     if(month < 10) month = "0"+month;
     otherFunc(year, month, inst);
   }
});
```

[You can try it in the context of your overall question here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6aG2n/2/).  It has to be a string to have the leading `0`, but that's ok in your case [since you're using it as a selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171775/help-how-to-make-days-enabled-in-ui-datepicker-after-month-change).

---

A more general approach for reuse would be to create a small function:

```
function leftPad(num) { 
  return (num < 10) ? '0' + num : num; 
}
```